# Retrieving Json from url success but no data shown on table

Tags: javascript, json

I tried running the code and I have successfully retrieve the json from the url as there is an alert success returned. However, when I try to retrieve the data, there is no result from the json file. Anyone can help me with this please?

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood&key=YOUR-API-KEY',
 dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
    drawTable(data);
 alert("Success!");
    }
});

function drawTable(data) {
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data[i]);
    }

}

function drawRow(rowData) {
   var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row); 
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.lat + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.lng + "</td>"));
 
 
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid #666;   
    width: 100%;
}
th {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
  font-weight: bold;    
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Json to HTML</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/table2.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<table id="personDataTable">

    <tr>
        <th>Lat</th>
        <th>Lng</th>
  
        
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have edited to add in the json data that I am trying to retrieve, I keep receiving a success connect to the webpage but there's no data that's retrieved.

```
{
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
  {
     "geocoder_status" : "OK",
     "place_id" : "ChIJa147K9HX3IAR-lwiGIQv9i4",
     "types" : [ "amusement_park", "establishment", "point_of_interest" ]
  },
  {
     "geocoder_status" : "OK",
     "place_id" : "ChIJzzgyJU--woARcZqceSdQ3dM",
     "types" : [ "amusement_park", "establishment", "point_of_interest" ]
  }
   ],
   "routes" : [
  {
     "bounds" : {
        "northeast" : {
           "lat" : 34.1373841,
           "lng" : -117.9220826
        },
        "southwest" : {
           "lat" : 33.8151707,
           "lng" : -118.3575585
        }
     },
```

Comment: what data like? you can check your for loop  is work

Comment: You can't select elements like this `var row = $("<tr />")`. Check jQuery documentation. Correct way would be: `var row = $("tr")`. Try and see if it works after this.

Comment: You may be experiencing a CORS issue with how your AJAX is set up. See here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors

Comment: i think you is Data structure problem

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide a data response representation.

Comment: @user615274 I have added the json data that I am trying to retrieve.

Comment: @ecg8 there is no CORS issue, I have successfully managed to connect to the webpage and successfully received the alert popup. however, there is no data that can be retrieved.

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac it still not working , there is empty data

Answer (score 1):

As other users commented, you should first check that the data you get from the api is correct. An alert saying that you reached that point is not a guarantee that you have the data you require. If on the other hand you have the correct data please consider this solution

Based on the data structure that you try to draw in the table I think it could be something like this:

```
[
    {
        "lat": 123,
        "lng": 456,
    }, {
        "lat": 789,
        "lng": -456,
    }, {
        "lat": 321,
        "lng": 956,
    }
]
```

Surely there will be more data but I imagine these are the relevant data in your case. If this is the case, one way to do it can be as follows:

```js
const dataset = [
    {
        lat: 123,
        lng: 456,
    }, {
        lat: 789,
        lng: -456,
    }, {
        lat: 321,
        lng: 956,
    }
];

function drawTable(dataset) {
    const rows = dataset.map(drawRow).join('');

    document.querySelector('#root').innerHTML = `
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Latitude</th>
                    <th>Longitude</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                ${rows}
            </tbody>
        </table>`;
}

function drawRow(data) {
    return `<tr>
        <td>${data.lat}</td>
        <td>${data.lng}</td>
    </tr>`;
}

// This call to the function in your example would be within the callback success in your ajax method
drawTable(dataset);
```

```css
table {
    border: 2px solid #666;
    width: 100%;
}

th {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Damn... I was typing the answer for the last 15 minutes. It happens a lot. Either typing code in an answer on SO sucks, or I'm simply still too slow / haven't gotten used to it.

Comment: funny fact! it happens to me all the time, in this club you are not alone

Comment: Great answer, btw. I'll post mine, nevertheless. The only difference is basically that you've used innerHtml and I have assumed that he wanted and had an actual table placeholder in HTML.

Comment: Thank you. You should publish your answer, remember that not only you answer to him/her, you could add something that is relevant to someone else in the future in a similar case.

Comment: Ofc. That's exactly why I am composing such long answers with lots of reference links - for OP (hopefully), but even more so for anyone who will stumble upon the question later in the future. Unfortunately, it seems to me that there is gazillion of people who basically come here just once with some question and if they don't receive an answer or quick fix within minutes, they are gone. Then again, nobody seems to read anymore, so I am wondering sometimes - what's the point? :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184505/discussion-between-nemanja-glumac-and-user615274).

Comment: it still does not work for me . my json is gotten from the google api and I can't change it to const dataset

Comment: I have added the json data that I am trying to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with improper understanding and usage of jQuery. First, your ajax is wrong. I mean, you literary have "YOUR-API-KEY" at the end of the link, so I have no idea how and why do you say that the data is successfully retrieved? But, let's say that it is, and let's say that you parsed JSON and/or manipulated data in a way that you end up with something like this:

```
data = [{lat: latValue0, lng :lngValue0}, {lat: latValue1, lng : lngValue1}, ...]
```

I mean, this is from what I've seen in your code: `data[i].lat` and `data[i].lng`

So, with that huge IF out of our minds, the actual process of drawing the table rows could be done like this:

```
function drawTable(data) {
  let table = $("#personDataTable");

  data.forEach(row => {
    table.append(`<tr><td>${row.lat}</td><td>${row.lng}</td></tr>`)
  });
}
```

That's it. You don't need much more. If you're not familiar with ES6 syntax, You can go to [Babel's website](https://babeljs.io/repl) and paste ES6 code on the left, and watch what it compiles to on the right. Btw, `forEach()` is preferred over "classical" `for` loop. They are doing the same job, but you have much less syntax and less room for error.

Btw, your mistake with jQuery's `.append()` was confusing appending strings with appending another element on the page which you select with `$`. Read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Further reading:

- [MDN: Template Literals (Template Strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [MDN: Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [MDN: Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: my json is something like this

Comment: {
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
    
         "types" : [ "amusement_park", "establishment", "point_of_interest" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
        
         "types" : [ "amusement_park", "establishment", "point_of_interest" ]
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 34.1373841,
               "lng" : -117.9220826
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 33.8151707,
               "lng" : -118.3575585
            }
         },